# LaTeX bibliography shows random digits after every entry

Tags: bibliographies

When compiling my LaTeX file, the bibliography shows (random?) numbers after every entry:

[image: Bibliography error]

I used the exact same template for bibliography style (.bst-file) a few years ago, and I noticed that I had to replace `\sc` with `\scshape`. Other than that there were no further errors. The only difference are the digits behind every bibliography entry.

I also tried other bibliography styles, however the problem persists, so I assume it has nothing to do with the bib style template. My .bib file is the following (also no changes in style, compared to previous documents I made)

```
@BOOK{ghsw14,
    AUTHOR =       {Gross and Hauger and Schr"oder and Wall},
    TITLE =        {Technische Mechanik 2},
    PUBLISHER =    {Springer Verlag},
    ADDRESS   =    {Darmstadt/Garching/Essen},
    PAGES =        {15-18},
    YEAR =         2014
}
@ARTICLE{voelckel08,
    AUTHOR =     {W.G.~Voelckel and H.~Trimmel},
    TITLE =      {Stellenwert der Luftrettung in der Traumaversorgung},
    JOURNAL =    {Notfall Rettungsmed},
    YEAR =       2008,
    NUMBER =     11,
    PAGES =      {240--245}
}
@Article{ruppert17,
    AUTHOR =     {M.~Ruppert and T.~van~Boemmel and R.~Lefering and W.~Fiala and M.~G"a"sler},
    TITLE =      {Einsatzspektrum in der Windenrettung},
    JOURNAL =    {Notfall Rettungsmed},
    YEAR =       2017,
    NUMBER =     20,
    PAGES =      {486--494}
}
```

I also cannot see the digits in the .bbl-file, which has the following code:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{ghsw14}
{\scshape Gross, Hauger, Schr"oder und Wall}: {\em Technische Mechanik 2}.
\newblock Springer Verlag, Darmstadt/Garching/Essen, 2014.

\bibitem{ruppert17}
{\scshape M.~Ruppert, T.~van Boemmel, R.~Lefering, W.Fiala, und M.~G"a"sler}:
  {\em Einsatzspektrum in der Windenrettung}.
\newblock Notfall Rettungsmed, No.~20, S.486--494, 2017.

\bibitem{voelckel08}
{\scshape W.G. Voelckel und H.~Trimmel}: {\em Stellenwert der Luftrettung in
  der Traumaversorgung}.
\newblock Notfall Rettungsmed, No.~11, S.~240--245, 2008.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Has anyone had a comparable issue or know what I am overlooking?

Comment: looks a bit like backref numbers, but without a complete example it is difficult to be sure.

Comment: Indeed, thank you! Slipped into my code via classic copy-and-pasting `\usepackage[plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels, pagebackref, hypertexnames=true]{hyperref}`...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is resolved from comments.

Answer (score 3):

Removing `pagebackref` does the trick (see comments to question).

I didn't realize the digits were links because nothing happened when I clicked on them in the TexStudio pdf-preview.